# SQL using the count in my sql

Tags: sql, oracle, count

Hello I have this SQL statement I am trying to get the count and see how many records it has. I know that I could do a select count(*) from tables and where clause but I am afraid i might loose some records or more would show. Can I do a count using all those columns in my select statement. I think I might need to use the With clause or something. Any help?

```
select hdr.ACCESS_IND,        
        hdr.SID,    
         hdr.CLLI,    
         hdr.DA,    
         hdr.TAPER_CODE,    
         hdr.CFG_TYPE  as CFG_TYPE,    
         hdr.IP_ADDR,    
         hdr.IOS_VERSION,    
         hdr.ADMIN_STATE,    
         hdr.WIRE_CENTER,    
         substr(hdr.SID_IO_PRI, 1, 8)    PRI_IO_CLLI,    
         substr(hdr.SID_IO_SEC, 1, 8)    SEC_IO_CLLI,    
         hdr.VHO_CLLI ,   
         hdr.CFG_TYPE ,
         dtl.MULTIPURPOSE_IND,
         lkup.code3 as shelf_type,
         dtl.access_ind
     from      RPT_7330_HDR    hdr  
     INNER JOIN   RPT_7330_DTL dtl on hdr.EID = dtl.EID
     INNER JOIN CODE_LKUP2 lkup ON LKUP.CODE1 = DTL.ACCESS_IND
     where    LKUP.CATEGORY='ACCESS_MAPPING' and  hdr.DT_MODIFIED = (select DT_MODIFIED    
                    from     LS_DT_MODIFIED    
                    where NAME = 'RPT_7330_HDR') 
                    and LKUP.CATEGORY='ACCESS_MAPPING'
                    and  hdr.ACCESS_IND;
```

Comment: Your fear is unwarranted.  If you don't believe me, find a client that tells you the recordcount  sqldeveloper will work.  Run the query you have and then do a count(*).

Comment: Oh i see, I ran the query @Peter answered and then did a count(*) and your right it gave me the same number of records. I was using TOAD and it only gives you 500 records at a time so an needed to scroll down to get another 500 records it was taking a long time especially when its in the 100k records. And I thought some records would might been lost because I added more columns and joined more tables to the query. I just wanted to test it before records and after records to see if it matches, but it does thanks!

Comment: You dont have to scroll down for row count on TOAD. There is option for row count. Check is help file of Toad. Downside is Toad will display few rows first then you can check row count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select count(*) from (
    select hdr.ACCESS_IND,        
        hdr.SID,    
         hdr.CLLI,    
         hdr.DA,    
         hdr.TAPER_CODE,    
         hdr.CFG_TYPE  as CFG_TYPE,    
         hdr.IP_ADDR,    
         hdr.IOS_VERSION,    
         hdr.ADMIN_STATE,    
         hdr.WIRE_CENTER,    
         substr(hdr.SID_IO_PRI, 1, 8)    PRI_IO_CLLI,    
         substr(hdr.SID_IO_SEC, 1, 8)    SEC_IO_CLLI,    
         hdr.VHO_CLLI ,   
         hdr.CFG_TYPE ,
         dtl.MULTIPURPOSE_IND,
         lkup.code3 as shelf_type,
         dtl.access_ind
     from      RPT_7330_HDR    hdr  
     INNER JOIN   RPT_7330_DTL dtl on hdr.EID = dtl.EID
     INNER JOIN CODE_LKUP2 lkup ON LKUP.CODE1 = DTL.ACCESS_IND
     where    LKUP.CATEGORY='ACCESS_MAPPING' and  hdr.DT_MODIFIED = (select DT_MODIFIED    
                    from     LS_DT_MODIFIED    
                    where NAME = 'RPT_7330_HDR') 
                    and LKUP.CATEGORY='ACCESS_MAPPING'
                    and  hdr.ACCESS_IND
) v;
```